# How to create a base window using WPF and the MahApps framework?

Tags: c#, xaml, frameworks, mahapps.metro

I am new to WPF and XAML and I am currently using the MahApps framework to get the Windows Metro theme for my application.

I am following along using this [guide](http://mahapps.com/guides/quick-start.html) to get the Metro theme incorporated.

My question is how do I create a base window that has the MahApps theme and then other windows can inherit from this base window so they also would get the theme.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a short how to for creating a base `MetroWindow` and it's usage.

1) Create a class with your base window (without any xaml code)

```
using System.Windows;
using MahApps.Metro.Controls;

namespace MahAppsMetroSample
{
    public class CustomBaseMetroWindow : MetroWindow
    {
        static CustomBaseMetroWindow()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CustomBaseMetroWindow), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CustomBaseMetroWindow)));
        }
    }
}
```

2) create a a theme resource dictionary in your solutio, call it `Generic.xaml` (it's only an example)

[image]

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:mahAppsMetroSample="clr-namespace:MahAppsMetroSample"
                    xmlns:controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls">

    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Themes/MetroWindow.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

    <Style TargetType="mahAppsMetroSample:CustomBaseMetroWindow" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type controls:MetroWindow}}">
        <Setter Property="TitleCharacterCasing" Value="Lower" />
        <Setter Property="WindowTransitionsEnabled" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="WindowTitleBrush" Value="Brown" />
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

3) use your custom window instead the `MetroWindow`

```
using MahApps.Metro.Controls;

namespace MahAppsMetroSample
{
    public partial class MainWindow : CustomBaseMetroWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
<mahAppsMetroSample:CustomBaseMetroWindow x:Class="MahAppsMetroSample.MainWindow"
                                          xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                                          xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                                          xmlns:Controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
                                          xmlns:mahAppsMetroSample="clr-namespace:MahAppsMetroSample"
                                          Title="MainWindow">

    <Grid>
    </Grid>
</mahAppsMetroSample:CustomBaseMetroWindow>
```

You can find this sample also in my GitHub MahAppsMetroSample [code-sample repository](https://github.com/punker76/code-samples).

Hope this helps!